# Open VPN on Linux: ERROR: Linux route add command failed: external program exited with error status: 2. How do I fix this?

Tags: ubuntu, routing, openvpn

Okay, so I'm running an open vpn client trying to connect to a server that's used by my school, and I'm having to fix errors in the config file to get the vpn to run on my ubuntu machine.

Error log:

```
2021-02-08 01:24:58 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET][server-ip]
2021-02-08 01:24:58 UDP link local: (not bound)
2021-02-08 01:24:58 UDP link remote: [AF_INET][server ip]
2021-02-08 01:24:58 WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this
2021-02-08 01:25:04 [server] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET][server ip]
2021-02-08 01:25:10 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
2021-02-08 01:25:10 /sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500
2021-02-08 01:25:10 /sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up
2021-02-08 01:25:10 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 10.255.255.36/24
Error: Invalid prefix for given prefix length.
2021-02-08 01:25:10 ERROR: Linux route add command failed: external program exited with error status: 2
Error: Invalid prefix for given prefix length.
2021-02-08 01:25:10 ERROR: Linux route add command failed: external program exited with error status: 2
Error: Invalid prefix for given prefix length.
2021-02-08 01:25:10 ERROR: Linux route add command failed: external program exited with error status: 2
Error: Invalid prefix for given prefix length.
2021-02-08 01:25:10 ERROR: Linux route add command failed: external program exited with error status: 2
2021-02-08 01:25:10 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

Config file:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote [server ip]
resolv-retry infinite
remote-cert-tls server
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
cipher AES-256-CFB
data-ciphers AES-256-CFB
auth SHA256
auth-user-pass
route 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0
route 192.168.20.0 255.255.255.0
route 192.168.30.0 255.255.255.0
```

I've tried push "route..." with the same response, and removing the route commands gives me the same set of error messages. Changing the route, including adding /24, just gives me more errors.

Also, is the vpn running in its current state? Thanks.

Edit: running using verb 3 gives me this at the end of the log:

```
2021-02-09 17:51:06 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 10.255.255.36/24
2021-02-09 17:51:06 /sbin/ip route add 192.168.10.0/24 via 10.255.255.1
2021-02-09 17:51:06 /sbin/ip route add 192.168.20.0/24 via 10.255.255.1
2021-02-09 17:51:06 /sbin/ip route add 192.168.30.0/24 via 10.255.255.1
2021-02-09 17:51:06 /sbin/ip route add 192.168.1.1/24 via 10.255.255.1
Error: Invalid prefix for given prefix length.
2021-02-09 17:51:06 ERROR: Linux route add command failed: external program exited with error status: 2
2021-02-09 17:51:06 /sbin/ip route add 192.168.10.1/24 via 10.255.255.1
Error: Invalid prefix for given prefix length.
2021-02-09 17:51:06 ERROR: Linux route add command failed: external program exited with error status: 2
2021-02-09 17:51:06 /sbin/ip route add 192.168.20.1/24 via 10.255.255.1
Error: Invalid prefix for given prefix length.
2021-02-09 17:51:06 ERROR: Linux route add command failed: external program exited with error status: 2
2021-02-09 17:51:06 /sbin/ip route add 192.168.30.1/24 via 10.255.255.1
Error: Invalid prefix for given prefix length.
2021-02-09 17:51:06 ERROR: Linux route add command failed: external program exited with error status: 2
2021-02-09 17:51:06 /sbin/ip route add 192.168.11.0/24 via 10.255.255.1
2021-02-09 17:51:06 Initialization Sequence Completed
^C2021-02-09 17:53:08 event_wait : Interrupted system call (code=4)
2021-02-09 17:53:08 /sbin/ip route del 192.168.10.0/24
2021-02-09 17:53:08 /sbin/ip route del 192.168.20.0/24
2021-02-09 17:53:08 /sbin/ip route del 192.168.30.0/24
2021-02-09 17:53:08 /sbin/ip route del 192.168.1.1/24
Error: Invalid prefix for given prefix length.
2021-02-09 17:53:08 ERROR: Linux route delete command failed: external program exited with error status: 2
2021-02-09 17:53:08 /sbin/ip route del 192.168.10.1/24
Error: Invalid prefix for given prefix length.
2021-02-09 17:53:08 ERROR: Linux route delete command failed: external program exited with error status: 2
2021-02-09 17:53:08 /sbin/ip route del 192.168.20.1/24
Error: Invalid prefix for given prefix length.
2021-02-09 17:53:08 ERROR: Linux route delete command failed: external program exited with error status: 2
2021-02-09 17:53:08 /sbin/ip route del 192.168.30.1/24
Error: Invalid prefix for given prefix length.
2021-02-09 17:53:08 ERROR: Linux route delete command failed: external program exited with error status: 2
2021-02-09 17:53:08 /sbin/ip route del 192.168.11.0/24
2021-02-09 17:53:08 Closing TUN/TAP interface
2021-02-09 17:53:08 /sbin/ip addr del dev tun0 10.255.255.36/24
2021-02-09 17:53:08 SIGINT[hard,] received, process exiting
```

So apparently it's trying to add these weird routes at the end that aren't even in the config file. Why is it trying to connect using 1?

Running verb 5 didn't give me much more, except:

```
WRR2021-02-09 18:01:46 us=534750 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,route 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0,route 192.168.10.1 255.255.255.0,route 192.168.20.1 255.255.255.0,route 192.168.30.1 255.255.255.0,dhcp-option DOMAIN [school_url],route 192.168.11.0 255.255.255.0 10.255.255.1,route-gateway 10.255.255.1,topology subnet,ping 10,ping-restart 60,ifconfig 10.255.255.36 255.255.255.0,peer-id 1'
```

ifconfig -a

```
enp2s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 5c:f9:dd:44:07:cc  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 6780  bytes 718813 (718.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 6780  bytes 718813 (718.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp1s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.141  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 2602:304:cd49:ce89:7339:c912:850e:503c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2602:304:cd49:ce89:30ac:f9d6:9b72:9fa8  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::6dbb:3d0f:ff63:d0da  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 68:5d:43:97:7b:8d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 348014  bytes 368671357 (368.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 232910  bytes 38136412 (38.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: Could you re-run the client with `verb 3` or even `verb 5` (not sure which) to see what exact commands it is trying to run?

Comment: @user1686 I added information from verb 3 and 5 above.

Comment: I wonder if these are even things you CAN fix.  It appears that the routes being pushed are invalid, ie the /24 netmask is not compatible with 192.168.1.1  (it would be 192.168.1.1/32 or 192.168.1.0/24)

Comment: Could you run `ifconfig` and post the output? It is possible that your physical interface is in the 192.168.1.0/24, and thus not accept that route.

Comment: @eventHandler See edit above - I ran ifconfig -a. Looks like you're right.